# PHP file upload, sending formdata object

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to upload a file, send it to javascript formData object and than via ajax to some php script which will put the file into database. It works fine when i upload a file in profile php, send it to formData object in javascript and send it back to profile.php. Problem is that when i want to send formData object to some other php script which isn't profile.php, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

profile.php

```
<form role="form" id="editUserProfile" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" class="file-input" accept="image/*"/></a>
    <button type="submit">Save</button
</form>
```

javascript.js

```
    $('#editUserProfile').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var aFormData = new FormData();

            aFormData.append("filename", $('#filename').get(0).files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "script.php",
                data: aFormData,
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

And than I want to check in some other php (script.php) script if file was uploaded.

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']) != false){
    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    $type = $size['mime'];
    $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    $size = $size[3];
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $maxsize = 99999999;

    if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize ){
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (image_type ,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?)");

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);

        $stmt->execute();
    }else{
        throw new Exception("File Size Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: hard to follow exactly how you want things to work. Can you itemize each step starting at AJAX submit?

Comment: Ok. I have a aFormData object with file in it, and i want it to send to script.php where where i will check if the object with file recieved successfully. The only problem is to step into if statement. I tested this case with the script where the form is and the code works well, but i want to have a function somewhere else and that is the problem.

Comment: `somewhere else` is very vague...please update question with far more specifics of what you expect to happen... mention files in steps. Your descriptions are far too loose to follow

Comment: I have 2 php scripts: profile.php and upload.php. In profile.php, i have a form where file is uploaded. After uploading a file in form, I append this file to a javascript object formdata, like i descriped before(script.js). When object is loaded with filedata i want to send it via ajax to upload.php. In upload.php I am checking if($_FILES) is set and that's the main thing for me. The problem is that ($_FILES) isn't set after sending formdata object via ajax to upload.php.

Comment: I also tried to send formdata object back to profile.php and executed this part of code(checking if($_FILES) is set and inserting to databased) and it worked. So the problem is only of sending the object with file data to upload.php and checking if($_FILES) is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added to jQuery.ajax and it works now:

```
processData: false,

contentType: false,
```